# Determing the Big(O) efficiency of a particular loop

Tags: java, big-o

I am being asked to determine the big O notation for this loop.

```
    int x = 1;
    int n = 1000;
    while (x < (n*n))
    {
        int y = n;
        while (y > 0)
        {
            y = y-1;
        }
        x = x+x;
    }
```

Now I see that is a nested loop. But this is definitely not N^2, correct? 
I understand what makes something O(n) or O(log(n)), but how would I go about determining for a specific loop such as this one?

Comment: complexity is `O(n^3)`

Comment: how did you reach this? @mangusta

Comment: it is better to refer to algorithms textbook, there is always a section at the beginning with thorough example-based explanation

Comment: you can try decomposing the loop into subprograms, analyze them separately and multiply the result.
so, inner while loop will execute n times, so it's N. in worst case, outer loop will execute n*n times, executing inner loop each time. thus, N^3.

Comment: the outer loop does not execute n*n times. are you guys taking note of x = x+x; @ilj

Comment: is the outer loop logarithmic? making it,  NLog(n) @ilj

Comment: more like n*log(n^2), but yes.

Comment: So thats it? O(n*log(n^2))?     the n^2 comes from the inner loop? @ilj

Comment: n for inner loop, log(n^2) for outer. you can rewrite outer loop as while ( i < log2(n*n) ) {i++; blah}

Comment: @Andy the big-oh notation does not count on the number of iterations, it is based on the upper bound of exec.time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inner loop runs from **n** to **0**, so it is ***O(n)***.

The outer loop

```
while (x < (n*n)) {
    ...
    x = 2*x;
}
```

is logarithmic, running from **1** to **n*n**, which would be ***O(log(n<sup>2</sup>)) = O(2 log n) = O(log n)***.

Since the loops are nested, you multiply the complexities to get ***O(n log n)***.